# Terminate mysql connection after multiple queries have executed

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I have some node.js code which fetches data from an API in a loop and runs mutliple mysql queries to update some rows.

The issue I have is that the script keeps running until I terminate the mysql connection with `connection.end()`. I am a newbie in asynchronous code. Where do I call the termination function so that it executes when all the queries have finished executing? What's the right design pattern for this? Would [waterfall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall) be any good?

This is a snippet from the code I have at the moment (error handling removed for simplicity):

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host, user, etc... });

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var url = "http://api.com?i="+i;

    request(url, function(error, response, body) {

        var data = JSON.parse(body);

        for (el in data) {
            connection.query(
                "UPDATE table SET col = ? WHERE symbol = ?",
                [
                    data[el].col,
                    el
                ]
            );
        }
    });
}

// this will run before all queries have executed
// resulting in an error
connection.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem here is that you are cycling in a synchronized way through the data here:

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
for (el in data) {
    connection.query(
         "UPDATE table SET col = ? WHERE symbol = ?",
         [
             data[el].col,
             el
         ]
     );
 }
```

while the `mysql` module handles the query in a callback style:

```
connection.query(query, function(error, rows, fields) {
    if (error) {
       return callback(error);
    } else {
       return callback(null,rows);
    }
});
```

where `callback` has the signature `callback(error,rows)`, so that you can handle the results in this way supposed to have a reusable function:

```
  var executeQuery = function(query,callback) {
        var self=this;
        this.connection.query(query, function(error, rows, fields) {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            } else {
                return callback(null,rows);
            }
        });
    }
```

and you can call in your code like

```
executeQuery(statement, function(error,rows) {
  //...
})
```

That said, you must consider that you are doing multiple queries to your database and it is not recommended to do this in for loop cycle. You should consider to use a better solution that could be a waterfall as you say or a promise all using the Promise paradigma.

Suppose that to have this nice function:

```
var promiseAllP = function(items, block) {
        var promises = [];
        items.forEach(function(item,index) {
          promises.push( function(item,i) {
              return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                return block.apply(this,[item,index,resolve,reject]);
              });
            }(item,index))
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }
```

that takes as input an array of items and a execution function that is `function(item,index,resolve,reject)` that has a resolve and reject functions of a Promise, so let's turn your `executeQuery` function in a Promise as well:

```
var executeQueryP = function(query) {
        var self=this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           self.connection.query(query, function(error, rows, fields) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                return resolve(null,rows);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you can process your data in a totally async way promisyfied:

```
promiseAllP(data,(item,index,resolve,reject) => {
    var query= "UPDATE table SET col = %s WHERE symbol = %s";
    // example: prepare the query from item in the data
    query = replaceInString(query,item.col,item);
    executeQueryP(query)
    .then(result => resolve(result))
    .catch(error => reject(error))    
})
.then(results => { // all execution completed
 console.log(results)
})
.catch(error => { // some error occurred while executing
  console.error(error)
})
```

where the `replaceInString` will help you to prepare the statement

```
   var replaceInString = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var rep= args.slice(1, args.length);
    var i=0;
    var output = args[0].replace(/%s|%d|%f|%@/g, function(match,idx) {
      var subst=rep.slice(i, ++i);
      return( subst );
    });
     return(output);
  },//replace,
```

This is what we have done here:

- Used native Promise only
- Turned your mysql query in a promise
- Called the statements against your data in a completely asynchronous way
- Used a Promise and Promise all paradigma, that let you collect the results of the Promise and return to the caller when all the functions are completed.
- Catched errors in all the statements execution
- Added a simply way to fulfill statements with parameters

Also notice the arrow function syntax `(param1, param2) =>` that simplify the way to write a function, that can help a lot with the Promise paradigma.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. And how about using async.parallel? Would that also be suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Well there are several frameworks that helps you, but since you are at the first stage I strongly suggest you to understand once what's going on here, so using the native `Promise` and the function I wrote, you can do the same in parallel concurrent execution using native modules only (browser or not).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I ended up solving it by a mixture of promises and counting the queries, something along the lines of this (not sure if this code actually works but the idea is there):

```
function fetchFromAPI() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var urls = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            urls.push("http://api.com?i="+i);
        }
        var data = [];
        var requestedUrls=0;
        urls.forEach(url=>{
            request(url, (err, response, body) {
                if(err) reject(err);
                data.push(JSON.parse(body));
                requestedUrls++;
                if(requestedUrls==urls.length) resolve(data);
            };
        });
    }
}

fetchFromAPI().then(data=>{
    mysql.createConnection({ user, hostname, etc... });
    var processedKeys=0;
    data.forEach(el=> {
        mysql.query("UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?", [el.name, el.id], (err, rows, fields) => {
            processedKeys++;
            if(processedKeys==data.length) {
                connection.end();
            }
        });
    }
}).catch(err=>{
    console.error(err);
});
```